# Swift: Stuck with a compiler error

Tags: swift

While exploring a structure read from a json file, I've got this message on the “if let” line which I'm stuck with:

'String' is not a subtype of '(String, AnyObject)'

The code is as follows:

```
       if let descriptions: Array<Dictionary<String,AnyObject>> = fields["description"] as? Array {

            let description = descriptions[0] 

            if let text:String = description["text"] as? String { // where the error occurs 
                poi.description = text
            }
        }
```

Comment: have you tried `let text = description["text"] as? String` ?

Comment: `String` is not an object, it is a `struct`, use `Any` in place of `AnyObject` or downcast.

Comment: @Zaph: With if let descriptions: Array<Dictionary<String,Any>> = fields["description"] as? Array { I've got Cannot cast from protocol type 'AnyObject?' to non-conforming type 'Array<[String : Any]>' (That's weird, the code was OK with Xcode beta 5)

Comment: BTW, the `Array<Dictionary<String,AnyObject>>` type can now be a much readable and concise `[[String:AnyObject]]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to unwrap what's read from the `description` dictionary:

```
if let text:String = description["text"]! as? String { // where the error occurs
     ...
}
```

But that's not safe, because if the key is not found in the dict, it throws a runtime exception. A safer way is:

```
if let text:String = (description["text"] as AnyObject?) as? String { // where the error occurs
    ...
}
```

However, I presume that you're using `NSJSONSerialization` to deserialize your json data, so a better way to do that is to stick with obj-c types rather than pure swift data types with generics:

```
if let descriptions = fields["description"] as? NSArray {
    let description = descriptions[0] as NSDictionary

    if let text = description["text"] as? String {
        let x = text
    }
}
```

More compact and much easier to read.

Comment: I finally ended up to rely on obj-c prior you suggested it. But it is a pity that pure swift syntax is so collocates when compared to ns.

Comment: There are 2 things to say: 1. swift is still in beta, and it's still missing some features (I'd say in primis better reflection/introspection support) - 2. The data source you're using (`NSDictionary` and `NSArray`) comes from obj-c - in this case interoperability is limited by the fact that obj-c doesn't have generics

Comment: I just tested the non obj-c version (which was the question I asked) and you answer it perfect. Thanks. One last question though, regarding the compatibility between NSArray with swift [] and NSDictionnary with [:]. Under the hood, is there any specific conversion code or are those object compatible (I mean no need to have hidden glue code)?

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca I suggest to read about [interoperability and collections](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-XID_46)

Answer (score 0):

Use the new syntax and less of it.

Test declarations: Dictionary of Array of Dictionary
//    let testFields: [String:[[String:Any]]]
or
//    let testFields: [String:[[String:String]]]

```
let testFields = ["description":[["text":"value"]]]  

if let descriptions = testFields["description"] {
    let description = descriptions[0]

    if let text = description["text"] as String? {
        println("text: \(text)")
    }
}
```

Output:

> text: value